on mobile when I open hamburger menu the X icon is not showing when I want to close the menu?
this is html,css,js code for navigation menu and hamburger menu:
<nav class="menu">
        <div class="hamburger">
             <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        
                </div>
        <ul class="menu-items">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#">Laptop Brands <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                <div class="mega-menu">
                    <div class="menu-row">
                        <div class="menu-column">
                            <h3>Asus</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Asus1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Asus2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-column">
                            <h3>Acer</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Acer1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Acer2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-row">
                        <div class="menu-column">
                            <h3>HP</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">HP1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">HP2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="menu-column">
                            <h3>Dell</h3>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Dell1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dell2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

.menu {
    background-color: grey;
    position: relative;
}

.menu-items {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
}

.menu-items > li {
    position: relative;
}

.menu-items > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-items > li > a:hover,
.menu-items > li:hover > a {
    background-color: darkgrey;
}

.dropdown:hover .mega-menu {
    display: flex;
}

.fa-caret-down {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.dropdown:hover .fa-caret-down {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.mega-menu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: grey;
    width: 600px;
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 20px;
}

.menu-row {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.menu-column {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 15px;
    min-width: 150px;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-column h3 {
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu-column ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-column ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    transition: background-color 0.3s;
}

.menu-column ul li a:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

/* Responsive Styles */
.hamburger {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 20px;
}

.hamburger i {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #ffd978;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

@media (max-width: 600px)  {    

    
.menu-items {
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: -100%;
        height: 100%;
        width: 300px;
        background-color: grey;
        transition: right 0.3s ease;
        padding-top: 60px;
    }

    .menu-items.active {
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
    }

    .hamburger {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Mobile Dropdown */
    .dropdown .mega-menu {
        display: none;
        position: static;
        transform: none;
        width: 100%;
        box-shadow: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .dropdown.active .mega-menu {
        display: block;
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const hamburger = document.querySelector('.hamburger');
    const menuItems = document.querySelector('.menu-items');
    const dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
    const barsIcon = '<i class="fas fa-bars"></i>';
    const timesIcon = '<i class="fas fa-times"></i>';

    // Initialize hamburger with bars icon
    hamburger.innerHTML = barsIcon;

    // Toggle hamburger menu
    hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (menuItems.classList.contains('active')) {
            menuItems.classList.remove('active');
            hamburger.innerHTML = barsIcon;
        } else {
            menuItems.classList.add('active');
            hamburger.innerHTML = timesIcon;
        }
    });

    // Toggle dropdown on mobile
    dropdown.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (window.innerWidth <= 767) {
            event.preventDefault();
            dropdown.classList.toggle('active');
            const caretIcon = dropdown.querySelector('.fa-caret-down');
            if (dropdown.classList.contains('active')) {
                caretIcon.style.transform = 'rotate(180deg)';
            } else {
                caretIcon.style.transform = 'rotate(0deg)';
            }
        }
    });
});

the problem is when I open hamburger menu on iphone or mobile the X icon is not showing.
I want to know if the problem is in html,css or in js.
I see it has to do with fas fa-times.
can someone correct me?
thanks
my url is :laptopdiscounthub.com

do not forget to load font-awesome too , alike : <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

load font-awsome as @
G-Cyrillus said and it will work.

I solved the problem in other way:
this is html :


<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 
var hamburger = $('.mobile-menu'),
    menu      = $('.menu'),
    sub_menu  = $('.sub-menu-wrapper'),
    menu_item = $('.has-sub-menu');

  hamburger.on('click', function() {
      menu.slideToggle();
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });

  menu_item.on('click', function() {
      $(this).children('.sub-menu-wrapper').slideToggle();
  });
  
}); 
    
</script>
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a, span {
  display: inline-block;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

.menu > ul {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
}

.menu > ul > li {
  background-color: #ff5722;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul li a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

ul li:hover a {
  color: #333;
}

.has-sub-menu > a::after {
  content: '';
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.has-sub-menu:hover > a::after {
  border-top-color: #333;
}

.sub-menu-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  left: -9999px;
  background: #fff;
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top .5s, opacity .5s;
}

.sub-menu {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: left;
}

.sub-menu-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ff5722;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: initial;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {
  color: #ff5722;
}

.sub-menu-heading a:hover {
  color: initial;
}

.sub-menu-wrapper a {
  color: #ff5722;
}

.has-sub-menu:hover > .sub-menu-wrapper {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 45px;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 30px;
  height: 25px;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;   
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: -2.5px;
    right:2%;
  display: none;
    
   
    
}

.bar {
  height: 3px;
  background-color:#ee6c4d;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
}

.mobile-menu.active .bar:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(6px) rotate(-45deg);
}

.mobile-menu.active .bar:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(45deg);
}

@media (max-width: 600px)  {    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    html, body {
        max-width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden; 
    } 
    .entry-title {    
        display:none;
    }
    entry-footer {                
        display:none;
    }

    .custom-container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;         
        height:100px;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position:fixed;
        margin-top:-100px;
        z-index: 1; /* Added z-index */
    }
    .section {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .first-section {
        margin-left: 2%;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        position:fixed;
    }
    .second-section {
        margin-right: 2%;
        justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    .icon-container {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1; /* Ensure the icon is on top */
    }
    .circle {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color:#ee6c4d;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .circle .fa-star {
        color:#ffd978;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .icon-container .icon-text {
        margin-left:2px;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size:24px;
        color:#333;
        font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
        z-index:1;
        position:relative;
    } 

    .mobile-menu {
        display: flex;
        z-index: 3; 
        position: relative;
            
    }

    .menu {
            top:0;
            right:0;
        padding-top:60px;
        display: none;
        background-color:grey;
        height:700px;
        width:250px;
        z-index: 2; 
        position: absolute; 
    }

    .has-sub-menu > a::after {
        content: '';
        border: 8px solid transparent;
        border-top-color:green;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-top:-12px;
    }

    .menu > ul > li {
        display: block;
        text-align: left;
        position: relative;
        color:green;
        font-size: 18px;
        margin-bottom: 10px; 
    }
    
    .menu > ul > li > a {
        color: green;
        font-size: 18px; 
    }

    .sub-menu a:hover {
        color: #333;
    }
    
    .has-sub-menu > a {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .has-sub-menu > a::after {
        position: absolute;
        right: 20px;
        top: 20px;
    }

    .sub-menu-wrapper {
        position: static;
        background: transparent;
        display: none;
        flex-wrap: wrap; 
    }

    .has-sub-menu:hover > .sub-menu-wrapper {
        display: flex; 
    }

    .sub-menu {
        width: 48%; 
        padding: 10px 5px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin-bottom: 15px; 
    }

    .sub-menu-heading {
        border-color: #fff;
        font-size: 18px; 
    }

    .sub-menu-wrapper a {
        color:green;
        font-size: 16px; 
    }

    .header-container {
        display: flex;
        width:100%;
        height:150px;
        flex-direction:row;
        background-color:#ee6c4d;
        margin-top:100px;

    }
    .header-section1 {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-start;
        flex-direction:column;
    }
    .header-section2 {
        display:flex;
        justify-content:flex-end;
    }
    h1 {
        padding-top:-20px;
        padding-left:20px;
        margin-bottom:0;
        font-size:21px;
    }
    ul {
        padding-left:20px;
        margin: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .icon {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .icon i {
        color:green;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .icon-text {
        font-size: 16px;
    }

    .header-section2 img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        object-fit: contain;
    } 
    
    .card-container {
        z-index:1;
        position: relative;
    }
}
 <nav class="menu">
          
      
 
          
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Laptop Brands</a>
        <div class="sub-menu-wrapper">
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>Asus</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">asus1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Asus2</a></li>
            
          </ul>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>Acer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acer1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acer2</a></li>            
          </ul>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>Dell</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dell1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Dell2</a></li>
                     </ul>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>HP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HP1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HP2</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
        <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">MacBooks</a>
        <div class="sub-menu-wrapper">
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>MacBooks pro</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pro1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pro2</a></li>
            
          </ul>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="sub-menu-heading"><a>MacBooks Air</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Air1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Air2</a></li>
            
          </ul>
               </div>
      </li>
</ul>
  </nav>  
   
 <div class="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
           
        </div>




As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
